# Excel Power Query Not Loading All Rows

Tags: excel, text, powerquery

I have a folder which contains a few text files. I want to load into excel power query from that folder as data connection for merging into another table later on. However, I found the load in PQ is incomplete.

E.g. a text file has total 278,703 lines. Excel Power Query only would only load 148,379 lines.

No filter has applied to any files.

I have tried to load the text file individually and it would come out to be the same as incomplete data set in Excel Power Query.

I am using W10 64 bit and O365.

Load text file individually into power query to see if I can get the complete dataset.

What can I do to get the complete dataset to load?

Comment: PowerQuery only loads or shows a preview of the data. You will need to load it into your Data Model or Table, to see all the data it has loaded.